# Find out current database name (MSSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-server, default-database

If I want to know the server I can use:
`@@SERVERNAME`

Is there an equivalent function for getting database/catalog name.

I know that we can set it in the script with `USE` statement but what if it wasnt set and I wanted to query within a sproc what db I was using.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`db_name()` will give you the name of the current database.

Comment: @logixologist: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Comment: I would have done it immediately but it has a timer set on it.

Answer (score 9):

This should do it:

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DataBaseName
```

Per [SQL Authority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/12/sql-server-get-current-database-name/)

Comment: How to get also the server name along with this ?

Comment: @rinilnath you can use `@@servername` like
`SELECT DB_NAME() AS DataBaseName, @@servername AS ServerName`

Answer (score 5):

db_name() will get you the name of database that you using.
you can see the result with:
`select db_name()`

Answer (score 4):

With **the MSSQL queries below**, you can check **the current database**:

```
SELECT DB_NAME()
GO
```

> master

In addition, if you don't specify a database on **sqlcmd**, **"master" database** is used **by default**.